# generate the id of a navigation property without the full path

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an ASP.NET 5 RC1 project with the following code:

Model:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public NavigationClass NavigationClass { get; set; }

}

public class NavigationClass 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public in FieldId2 FieldId2 { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
@model MyClass
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.NavigationClass.FieldId2,Viewbag["MySelectList"])
```

renders as

```
<select id="MyClass_NavigationClass_FieldId2" name="MyClass_NavigationClass_FieldId2">
```

How do I render without the full path class name and navigation class name?
i.e.

```
<select id="FieldId2" name="FieldId2">
```

or

```
<select id="FieldId2" name="MyClass_NavigationClass_FieldId2">
```

by still using the lambda expression

I know I can hardcode the id in the view but  I still want to use the 
`DropDownListFor` e.g.

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.NavigationClass.FieldId2,Viewbag["MySelectList"])
```

or something similar

Comment: It does not generate `name="MyClass_NavigationClass_FieldId2"` - it does generate `name="NavigationClass.FieldId2"`. But why would you want to remove the prefix (meaning it will not bind to your model when you submit the form)

Comment: It will bind according to the name as I recall not the id so if the id shows shortened it will bind to the name. I have a common jquery function that uses that specific name across my whole project so that is why I want the id short in my html rendered.

Comment: What does that have to do with it? If your have a jquery function it should be accessing it by its `id` and you can give the element whatever id you want - `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.NavigationClass.FieldId2,Viewbag["MySelectList"], new { id = "FieldId2" }) `

Comment: Didn't know you could override the standard html properties like that. You should put that in the answer and I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly your `DropDownListFor()` method is not generating

```html
<select id="MyClass_NavigationClass_FieldId2" name="MyClass_NavigationClass_FieldId2">
```

It is actually generating

```html
<select id="NavigationClass_FieldId2" name="NavigationClass.FieldId2">
```

And you do not want to change the `name` attribute because it would not bind to your model when you submit the form.

You can however change the `id` attribute for use in a jQuery function by using an overload that accepts `htmlAttributes`

```cs
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.NavigationClass.FieldId2, Viewbag["MySelectList"], new { id = "FieldId2" })
```

which will generate

```html
<select id="FieldId2" name="NavigationClass.FieldId2">
```